# how to delete an input field in knockoutjs template in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, onepage-checkout, knockoutjs

On checkout page, there is a company field that I need to remove from the shipping address form. Furthermore, I need to change the city and region fields to make them dependent dropdowns.

I have overriden `checkout_index_index.xml` layout definition. I have just removed the corresponding item for company, and then refresh the page, but the field is still appearing.

How to do it?

Comment: did u clear var/cache, var/page_cache and var/generation ?

Comment: I don't have cache enabled since I am in development mode, and in fact, when I change any phtml file, any layout for block and container definitions and js or css files, changes are reflect immediately. I have the problem with company field because this is controlled by knockoutjs, what is difficult to manage.

Comment: or maybe I need to do something similar when I remove a block or container, by mean of some instruction to remove that field